# Get and Save particular Excel file in same location using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Asp.Net MVC application, Visual Studio 2013, SQL Server Data base

There is a particular location in my system's local drive i.e., c:/Files/Exim_Files/ , where a lot of excel(.xlsx) files are sitting. 
I want to get the particular file from that location and save it programmatically (without Save pop up) in same location with same/different name. while saving the excel data should not be lost, file should be as it is, just I need to save/SaveAs it again.

How can I achieve this requirement?

Note that I am using Virtual Machine and inside Virtual Machine: Microsoft Office is not installed. So the code will have to work without Microsoft Office installation in the machine. I can only use Microsoft Office in my host machine.

### Edit

In below code, I am using Aspose.Cells to save the Excel file from 1 location to another.

I am getting the particular File from sharedLocation in array "l_strFileUploadPath" and then checking, if the file that I am getting from user exists in shared location, then I want to save/SaveAs that
file into different location (defined in 'string str') along with entire data (say I want to import the data as well while Saving the Excel in different location).

The issue I am facing is that, the file that is getting saved in C: drive, is not saving the data which is present inside the Excel. It seems it is creating a new excel file in c: drive with same name (x-TECHNICAL_DIT_BUDV01_RV124_R01_2015_Test.xlsx) having 2 sheets. 
1 is 'sheet 1' and another is 'Evaluation Warning' sheet.

How can I remove the 'Evaluation Warning' sheet and what is the method of saving the exact file (along with data) from shared drive to c: drive, as per my code.

This is the first time using Aspose.Cells to get and Save/SaveAs the file from 1 location to another.

```
protected void getFileAndSave()
{
    string[] l_strFileUploadPath = Directory.GetFiles("//181.184.11.435/share//Temp/New folder");

    foreach (var filename in l_strFileUploadPath)
    {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
            string p_filename = "x-TECHNICAL_DIT_Test.xlsx"; //this is the file I am getting from user

            if (fileName == p_filename)
            {
                //-- Using Aspose.Cells
                    Workbook wb = new Workbook();

                    Worksheet worksheet = wb.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
                    worksheet.Name = "Technical Data";

                    //Save workbook with export cell as true
                    OoxmlSaveOptions opts = new OoxmlSaveOptions();
                    opts.ExportCellName = true;
                    wb.Save(str + file, opts);

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you just want to copy the file as is? not make changes? cant you just "copy" it?

Comment: @BugFinder: I want to get the file and save/SaveAs to that file in same location (So that the metaData info -- app.xml file of that particular file shall change, once I save/SaveAs the file)

Comment: Then you will need excel on the server.

Comment: @BugFinder: There is another application using the same thing, is working fine without having to install Microsoft Excel. They are using Aspose.Cells But I have no idea about Aspose.Cells Could you help me with some solution please.

Comment: We arent here to recommend software/components or teach you how to use them. If you wish to use a 3rd party app, then your choice, you do the research

Comment: @BugFinder: Please note that I was not asking to teach me about Aspose.Cells I just told the scenarios of not installing the MS Office.
            I was asking the solution for how get excel file from particular location and Save/SaveAs that excel file in same location programatically.

Comment: @BugFinder: I have Edited my posted question based on my investigation using Aspose.Cells , I am facing few issues. Kindly help me to resolve them.

Comment: of course your codes making a new spreadsheet, you at no point ask it to load the name of the old one... seriously you need to try - an this would be a whole new question..

Answer (score 0):

It seems for me that you just want to copy the file.

Take a look at [File.Copy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328773(VS.71).aspx)

```
File.Copy(@"c:\excel.xsl", @"c:\other\excel.xsl");
```

EDIT for comment:

I think it will be hard to change app.xml metadata without just manually looking what changes are made there during save/saveAs and then trying to understand how to copy this behavior and change it programmatically inside that file.

Comment: :I want to get the file and save/SaveAs that file in same location (So that the metaData info -- app.xml file of that particular file shall change, once I save/SaveAs the file)

Comment: I think the app.xml meta data info changes once you are Saving/SaveAs the file.
Suppose I got the file from User1 (which he generated from his machine) in particular location. 
So once I said Save/SaveAs to his file in same location; in both the cases app.xml meta data info will differ as per my understanding. Once it differs my work will be done. So I am in need of solution to Save/SaveAs that file.

Comment: Can you just look what changes are made in this file (open it and look) and try to copy this behavior in your application?

Comment: I have Edited my posted question based on my investigation using Aspose.Cells , I am facing few issues. Kindly help me to resolve them.